# Why doesn't the INotifyPropertyChanged work?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, inotifypropertychanged

I used a Multibinding to bind some properties and use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify these properties'changes.But sadly,it seems that the INotifyPropertyChanged didn't work. The PropertyChangedEventHandler "PropertyChanged" was null all the time.

Questions:

A. Could you please tell me why the event is null?In my mind,there should be a default   method for the event PropertyChangedEventHandler,am I wrong?(Resolved,thanks!)

B. Just like some friends said,I tried again without using the INotifyPropertyChanged.But the target's property's value seems to be not changed...

---

1. Properties

   ```
   public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftOffsetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("LeftOffset", typeof(double), typeof(NetworkTaskLable), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
   public static readonly DependencyProperty TopOffsetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TopOffset", typeof(double), typeof(NetworkTaskLable), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0d, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

   public double LeftOffset
   {
       get { return (double)GetValue(LeftOffsetProperty); }
       set { SetValue(LeftOffsetProperty, value); }
   }
   public double TopOffset
   {
       get { return (double)GetValue(TopOffsetProperty); }
       set { SetValue(TopOffsetProperty, value); }
   }
   ```
2. Multibinding (It seems work well.By using the converter to calculate a location which is affected by "TopOffset" and "LeftOffset")

   ```
   var multibinding = new MultiBinding() { Converter = new BeginAndStartDateToLeftConverter_NetworkTaskLable(), ConverterParameter = NetworkView };
   multibinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Start"));
   multibinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("StartDate") { Source = NetworkView });
   multibinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("LeftOffset") { Source = this });
   MainCanvas.SetBinding(LeftProperty, multibinding);
   ```
3. INotifyPropertyChanged

   ```
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   public void CallPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
   {
       if (PropertyChanged != null)//It seems to be null all the time!!!And the properties'changes were never notified!!!
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
   }
   ```
4. Notify the change

   ```
   SetValue(LeftOffsetProperty, moveAdorner.LeftOffset);
   CallPropertyChanged("LeftOffset");
   SetValue(TopOffsetProperty, moveAdorner.TopOffset);
   CallPropertyChanged("TopOffset");
   ```

Comment: You have dependency properties, but this interface is applied to common properties with the function call in the setter.

Comment: Thank you,vorrtex.But the reason may not be like you said.I tried to notify a common property,the event was still null...

Comment: Vorrtex meant that in your case the Binding engine listen to dependency property changes which implemented internally in WPF. So there is no handler for the PropertyChanged.

Comment: I'll try to explain it more clear. There are two mutually exclusive ways to update UI from code: 1) using DependencyProperties; 2) using common properties with implemented INotifyPropertyChanged. You have chosen the first way, so you can remove the PropertyChanged event and related functions from your class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for dependency properties. Binding will track changes of these properties automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Set `Mode=TwoWay` anywhere in your binding ?

Comment: No no. You should never add any additional logic to the CLR property wrapper for a Dependency Property since it isn't guaranteed to be called. Second, there is no need to raise PropertyChanged for a Dependency Property

Comment: Thanks, Meleak. Cleared that out.

Comment: Thanks,Meleak.Just like you said,DependencyProperty doesn't need to raise PrpertyChanged.But how to notify the changes?It may change automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override OnPropertyChanged and check to see if the property is the one you are looking for.

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Property == MyProperty)
    {
        // do something
    } 
    base.OnPropertyChanged(e);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks,Tom!It reminds me that OnProertyChanged() might be the defalt method for the event ProertyChanged.I tried yoour way,the event ProertyChanged was still empty(:P),but OnProertyChanged() was called in this time.Could you please asked some further questions,thanks a lot.   

1.Why the event was still null,but the method OnPropertyChanged() was called?

Comment: Dependency Properties don't support the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation which is why the PropertyChanged event isn't working. To have a dependency property you need to inherit from DependencyObject which exposes the OnPropertyChanged method which supports dependency properties.